# Changing Default Route on MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, routes

im trying to change the route of my solution to make it start with the controller that is called "formulariocontroller" and the action "formulario", i already looked up some tutorials here and questions and i thought i was doing it right but i cant make it work, its gives me this:

[image]

here is the code of my RouteConfig.cs

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SolucionFinal
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new
        {controller = "FormularioController",action = "Formulario",id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and of my controller:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Formulario()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modifique esta plantilla para poner en marcha su aplicación ASP.NET MVC.";

            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Formulario(string text)
        {

            Session["Text"] = text;
            return RedirectToAction("Exito", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult Exito()
        {


            ViewBag.Message = Session["Text"];

            return View();
        }


    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: The code you have posted is for `HomeController` (in which case the route defaults should be `... new {controller = "Home", action = "Formulario", ...`). If it's actually `FormularioController`, then the defaults should be `... new {controller = "Formulario", ...`

Comment: i changed the name of the HomeController to FormularioController, then just changed it on the routes file, still dont work.

Comment: What's not working? (and it needs to be `new {controller = "Formulario", ..`, not `new {controller = "FormularioController", ..`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new
        {controller = "Formulario",action = "Formulario",id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
```

Change the name of controller to `Formulario` from `FormularioController`

Answer (score 0):

ok, i solved it, i change the folder "home" name to "formulario" and it worked, this was the folder where the views were located.

noob mistake.

[image]